# How to change color of the snapping window from default orange

Tags: compiz

I was wondering if it is possible to change the color of the snapping windows from default orange to another color?

Comment: Thank you everyone I got it figured out thanks to all of your suggestions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this there are various applications like compiz, gnome tweak tool, my unity, ubuntu tweak ... try installing Ubuntu Tweak. For Ubuntu 12.04/11.10/11.04 just copy the following ppa and paste in the terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run the commands one by one:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

That installs the `tualatrix` PPA. Before installing this or other PPA's, it's advisable to read this so you understand the possible risks. (However, the `tualatrix` PPA is quite popular and its author is well-trusted in the community.)

- [Are PPA's safe to add to my system and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out)

After installation download themes from http://gnome-look.org/ and install...

Comment: Upvote for suggesting Ubuntu-Tweak over CCSM--CCSM can frack up your system, and Tweak can give you the piece of mind that is stability. :)

Answer (score 3):

If you like like to change just the color, you can change it using CompizConfig Settings Manager.

Run this in terminal to install it:

`sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`

After it install, run the application.

You'll get a warning saying "CCSM is an advanced tool. Use with caution." If you understand the risks of using CCSM, click OK and continue.

Scroll down to Window Management > Grid and click on the Appearance tab. Then, you can change the fill and outline color from orange to other colors.

Answer (score 0):

The orange is part of a theme if you want to change theme go [HERE](http://gnome-look.org/index.php?xcontentmode=167)

Download the theme (gtk3) you want and extract it then run `sudo nautilus` in terminal and put the folder you extracted in /usr/share/themes and install a tool like my unity 
`sudo apt-get install myunity` to change it. You can change icons the same way except put them in usr/share/icons.